# Wars take decades to fight

Tags: stellaris

I have declared a subjugation war against my neighbour empire and I have occupied **all** of their systems and destroyed their entire fleet, including their civilian ship; yet they still do not give up. Apparently, the warscore is only affected by attrition (which increases over time), occupation, and the number of ships destroyed which is **not proportional to the total number of ships**.

With this issue, I just wait for years until the attrition is high enough for me to enforce my demands.

What's going on exactly?

Comment: FWIW, if you have occupied all of their systems and planets, and have made claims on each of them, you can win and wipe them all out by choosing the "status quo" option; you don't have to use the "achieve war goals" option. The former has substantially lower requirements and will still result in the elimination of the enemy empire given the conditions I mentioned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The acceptance scope for "Achieve war goals" in a subjugation war is the sum from the following parts:

- Demanding Surrender: -100 (constant)
- Vassalize Wargoal: -100 (constant)
- Penalty for demanding unoccupied systems:  -10 x systems (optional)
- War Exhaustion: 0 to +100 (percent of war exhaustion of enemy)
- Occupation: 0 to +100 (percent of occupation of enemy systems)
- Relative Navy Strength: 0 to +50 (represents the strength of you navy vs. enemy)

You can see your current scope and its composition in the respective war window by hovering over the score number next to "Archive war goals". Example:

[image]

Your enemy will accept once the scope is > 0, which requires you to earn the sum of +200 points through war exhaustion, occupation and relative navy strength.

The navy strength is the important part here, because with a high number your enemy will surrender before he reaches 100% war exhaustion and/or before you have taken 100% of systems (e.g. 75% of systems plus 75% war exhaustion would work). On the other hand if your navy has equal strength you need to both have taken all systems and the enemy needs to have 100% war exhaustion to earn 200 points.

Number of ships factors into the war exhaustion, but does not directly effect the acceptance score.

In your case your relative navy strength might not be that high, so you really have to continue fighting until your enemy reaches 100% exhaustion.

Another factor that is often overlooking is that the occupation score includes the systems of any potential war ally of your enemy. So you will have to also conquer those systems to get to 100% occupation. If they are any allies they will be listed in the respective war window on the top right side.

**Tip:**

Defending planets does not add to the war exhaustion of the defender (only to the attacker). So if you want your enemy to reach 100% war exhaustion quickly focus on space battles.

Answer (score 1):

Planetary occupation can also affect the ability to force surrender as well, if memory serves correct. Did you make sure to send ground forces to capture all the planets their systems had, if any existed?

Comment: Yes, I occupied all of their planets.

Comment: I want to ask for modifiers, but I'm not entirely sure if that would even be a big help in figuring that out myself.

Comment: @PradanaAumars: Usually in situations like this, it's likely that *something* was still missed. Most likely, there's a planet some place you're not aware of, or some systems you haven't flipped.

Comment: @Ellesedil So the occupation of every enemy system and planet guarantees a forced surrender?

Comment: @PradanaAumars The occupation of all systems and planet can be an important part in forcing a surrender, but it will not be sufficient on its own. You also need at least 50% war exhaustion or more depending on your relative naval strength. See my answer for details.